# DocX C# library changing page format on InsertSectionPageBreak

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I am working with **DocX** a library for creating Microsoft .docx files inside
c#. https://docx.codeplex.com/

I am loading an preexisting file into the program and then adding content. 
It was the easiest way to get a pre defined header. I noticed that if
I use `InsertSectionPageBreak` the page format of all pages created in this way
will change from A4 to letter.

I tried with a fresh template file (empty file) and the results were the same.

```
var doc = DocX.Load(fileName);
doc.InsertSectionPageBreak();
doc.InsertSectionPageBreak();
doc.InsertSectionPageBreak();
doc.SaveAs(path + filenaming + ".docx");
```

Everything else is working fine. file creation, saving content.

The default value for A4 is `doc.PageWidth = 800;` but its not working on `sectionPageBreak` pages.

Comment: Please tell how you can work around it?

Comment: Still did not find a awnser. The printed version looks ok, but not the way it should. You could manualy change to A4 but its a drag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution! For me it works with the following code:

```
        Novacode.Paragraph p = docx.InsertParagraph(someText, false, someFormat);
        p.InsertPageBreakAfterSelf();
```

or just add empty paragraph:

```
        Novacode.Paragraph p = docx.InsertParagraph(string.Empty, false);
        p.InsertPageBreakAfterSelf();
```

Thus if we insert page without inserting section it will no break the format!